# Automated testing: Tool for Visualizing and archiving test results

Tags: unit-testing, junit, automated-tests

I have created some automated software tests for a project, which collect the results in a junit xml file structure.

What I am looking for is a web-based tool/solution to display the test results (provided as junit xml files), like what tests have been run, in which time, how many have succeeded, failed, error, skipped,..., in a nice way, with the ability to click on various results/buttons etc. to get additional details or to select a different view on the data (e.g. show me a graphical representation of a given test for the last 10 days...). This database is being updated externally, so only need to store, organize and provide views on the xml file results. No build or internal test execution is required.

If you have any idea of such a tool that would be helpful, otherwise I will update this question to make it more clear what I am looking for, or where to get such information.

P.S. I have looked into using CDash for those purposes, but CDash seem to generate more problems as to use CDash for the purpose of archiving and displaying automated test results.

Answer (score 1):

[Teamcity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) will do just that, and is free up to a limit.

Comment: Teamcity seems also to include building software, which is something I do not need. Also, I am running the tests externally, and just want my xml files to be organized and viewed.

Comment: Well, it's a platform. You can configure it to do many things.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but it seems that [**Jenkins Continuous Integration**](http://jenkins-ci.org/) is exactly what you ask for. It's free and has a nice web interface.